# swift custom UIAlertViewDelegate not work

Tags: swift, delegates

I am an android developer.

I want to use custom `UIAlertViewDelegate` in my code.

demo like

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIAlertViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
        println(buttonIndex)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func onClick1(sender: UIButton) {

        // define here not work
        let delegate = MyUIAlertViewDelegate()

        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "title", message: "message", delegate: delegate, cancelButtonTitle: "cancel", otherButtonTitles: "other","hello")

        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.Default

        alert.show()

    }
}

// define here works
// let delegate = MyUIAlertViewDelegate()


class MyUIAlertViewDelegate : UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {
    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
        println("click" + String(buttonIndex))
    }
}
```

but it not work.
why?

Comment: @Ramshad
i want to do something after button click just like UIAlertAction in ios8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed when you are creating a UIAlertView called "alert" you set message to message, for demo purposes this wont work unless message is a variable with a string value.

Also you are calling alert.show() in nothing! it needs to be called by something or somewhere, so in the example I have done below it is in viewDidAppear.

Please copy and paste this code if you need to it works perfectly, and please don't hesitate to ask any questions.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    alert.show()
}

}

class MyUIAlertViewDelegate : NSObject, UIAlertViewDelegate {
func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    print("click" + String(buttonIndex))
}
}

let delegate = MyUIAlertViewDelegate()
let alert = UIAlertView(title: "warning", message: "This is a message", delegate: delegate, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
```

Comment: If this answer solve your problem means accept the answer .Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Subclass as viewcontroller ,instead of nsobject

```
       class ViewController: UIViewController ,UIAlertViewDelegate{
             }
```

Add a button in storyboard or create yourself.Then
in button action add the given code.

```
       var  alert = UIAlertView(title: " Your Title", message: "your message", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok", otherButtonTitles: "Cancel")

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.Default

    alert.show()
```

Then

```
           func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        println("click",buttonIndex)

    if buttonIndex == 0 {

        println("ok")
    }else {
        println("Cancel")
    }
       }
}
```

You can customize as you need
Hope it helps

Comment: yes, this works. but why my code not work ? 
i think they are the same

Comment: try to subclass to viewcontoller instead of nsobject.And where the alert show works.Where is your button click

Comment: Your comment is helpful Lydia and correct, I think aotian16 just wanted their code correcting however. But nice thinking with sub-classing

Comment: thanks to all. I think it maybe the object was destroy when went out the method

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following many times actually, you can try this as well.

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

```
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    })))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```